# Dependency installation failing when I try to create an environment for a flask app on AWS EB

Tags: python, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, openai-api, langchain

Newbie here. I am playing through Langchain tutorials and got a simple python app to connect OpenAI to my local txt documents and answer questions based off that. It works fine on my local, but when I try to deploy it on AWS EB, the environment creation step fails. This is the relevant code https://github.com/moreshk/GPTFlaskUI/blob/main/app.py and the requirements file is https://github.com/moreshk/GPTFlaskUI/blob/main/requirements.txt I understand the requirements file is a bit of an overkill but I tried with succinct versions as well and they all thrown the same error. Engine log files do not seem to be particularly helpful as it does not provide more detail than saying dependency failed. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to setup a virtual environment and see if the dependency install works, it caused an issue with hnswlib installation which got resolved by setting HNSWLIB_NO_NATIVE: "1". I was unable to replicate this serverside so this might be a bit of a red herring.

Comment: Managed to resolve this. It was a combination of memory and dependecies issues. The default memory was proving to be too less, so increased that and scaled down the dependencies to the absolute bare minimum. Details on git.